# PHP strange behaviour in word currency

Tags: php, post

Hello everyone i am trying to make a post request in code using php. When i use as a key for my database the word 'currency' i get 'cy' when the post request reaches my database! First time seeing this behaviour! Any help appreciated. Using the posting url only on a browser works but not in php. I am showing you the code below:

```
$myvars = "api_key=1555222" . "&time=" .$unixepochtime. "&currency=EUR" . "&sign=".$signvalue;

settype($myvars,"string");
echo " ".$myvars." "; 
/* this shows me api_key=1555222&time=14445454545¤cy=EUR&sign=kiokossdsdasdafererasdasd
instead of
 api_key=1555222&time=14445454545&currency=EUR&sign=kiokossdsdasdafererasdasd
*/
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

echo $response
```

I get an error as a result because the sign is being created using currency word! Please help!

Comment: How is `$unixepochtime` defined?

Comment: $unixepochtime=time(); like this

Comment: There must be something weird going on with encoding or anything, all PHP versions by default show the expected string: https://3v4l.org/3lq02

Comment: This is really driving me crazy! Encoding of the php file? I am writing in UTF-8 ...

Comment: Maybe calling urlencode on the key-value pairs and dumping them then helps to understand the error.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Are you going to store query strings and the one named `currency` is truncated to `cy`?

Comment: urlencode seems ok no strange character. The problem is that i must use and send the currency word correctly after the url is created. I cant do it because i get cy and a strange character infront of cy. By the way urlencode does not seem to show any strange character!

Comment: The "strange character" you're getting infront of cy is actually the "general currency sign" (`&curren;`)

Comment: Another (easy) "solution"/workaround would be to place "currency=..." at the beginning of your string, so `&curren` doesn't get replaced, because it is now `?currency`.

Comment: Let me try this and give you feedback

Comment: I added the currency word at the start and still does not work. I get a message saying {"error_no":1005,"msg":"Invalid Signature"} so i guess is something with the signature variable which is in md5 format. It works if i write the url to the browser but not by using php!!! Any thoughts?